# Issue with quotes in jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this Function that retrive a xml for a listview content :

```
function xmlParser(data) {
            xml = data;

            $('#load').fadeOut();

            $(xml).find("item").each(function () {

                var title = $(this).find("title").text();
                var description = $(this).find("description").text();

            $("#list").append('<li><h2>' + title + '</h2><font style="white-space:normal; font-size: x-small;">' + description + '</font><br/><button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('+"'description'"+')">share!</button></li>');
        });
        $('#list').listview('refresh');
    }
```

after the content, the button share is display but when I click on, it displays 'description' and not the content of the variable (a text).
I think my quotes ' and " are misplaced but I can't fix it.
Some help will apreciated.

Comment: Those are quotes, not commas. And yes, as is obvious from the syntax highlighting here (and presumably in your editor; if not, get a better editor), the quotes are incorrect.

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro.

Comment: what is the variable a.text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the quotes around the variable name are causing it to be interpreted as a string literal. You need to change the syntax:

```
$("#list").append('<li><h2>' + title + '</h2><font style="white-space:normal; font-size: x-small;">' + description + '</font><br/><button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(\''+ description + '\')">share!</button></li>');
```

Better still would be to put the `description` in a `data` attribute and hook the `click` event handler using unobtrusive JS instead of an outdated `on*` event attribute:

```
function xmlParser(data) {
  xml = data;
  $('#load').fadeOut();
  $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
    var title = $(this).find("title").text();
    var description = $(this).find("description").text();
    $("#list").append('<li><h2>' + title + '</h2><font style="white-space:normal; font-size: x-small;">' + description + '</font><br/><button data-description="' + description + '">share!</button></li>');
  });
  $('#list').listview('refresh');
}

$('#list').on('click', 'li button', function() {
  window.plugins.socialsharing.share($(this).data('description'));
});
```

Comment: LOL yeah, I misread it. The sentence is *much* clearer now. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice. I just put the second part in my pagebeforecreate event and it works well.

Answer (score -2):

```
                      $("#list").append('<li><h2>' + title + '</h2><font style="white-space:normal; font-size: x-small;">' + description + '</font><br/><button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share("' + description + '")">share!</button></li>');
            });
            $('#list').listview('refresh');
        }
```

try this one.

I only updated this line.

```
 $("#list").append('<li><h2>' + title + '</h2><font style="white-space:normal; font-size: x-small;">' + description + '</font><br/><button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share("' + description + '")">share!</button></li>');
```

Comment: Why? What did you change? Why did you change it? Code dumps are not *useful* answers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder dude look above answer it's same as my code but there is only one difference that my code without description. ha  ha ha ha

Comment: I think TJ's point is more about the fact you just dumped code in your answer. The point of SO is to educate people so it's far more beneficial to them if you explain why their code doesn't work and explain why you made the changes you have.

Comment: That's another thing: When you notice you've (innocently) duplicated a previous answer and not added anything of benefit not in that other answer, delete your duplicate. It serves no useful purpose, and increases noise on the site.